# start command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am wanting to run a batch file which builds visual studio project in another window and then return to original window and execute later commands.

but following command immediately prints LetterTwo without waiting for complete solution building

```
echo LetterOne
start /WAIT msbuild sim.sln
echo LetterTwo
```

Comment: replace `start /WAIT` by `cmd /c` and tell us if it works

Comment: What is `msbuild`, a batch file?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it builds solution in same window, rather opening new window for solution building

Comment: ok, then try `start /WAIT cmd /c msbuild`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , nop, it builds solution in another window but executes next command "echo LetterTwo" in first window before complete solution building . instruction 2 and 3 executes simultaneously rather sequentially.

Comment: then create a batch file that calls msbuild and start /WAIT that. I've done the test with a standard `TIMEOUT` executable, and your method works. Seems that msbuild is special. I don't have it here to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have able to solve the problem by modifying @stephan code a little bit

```
    @echo off
    start msbuild <solution>
    :loop
    timeout 1 >nul
    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq msbuild.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "msbuild.exe">NUL
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto loop
    echo finished.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments to the question, it seems, `msbuild` doesn't behave, like one would guess. So your only way is to "wait manually":

```
start "MyUglyApplication" msbuild sim.sln
:loop
timeout 1 >nul
tasklist /v | find "MyUglyApplication" && goto :loop
echo finished.
```

Give the new window a unique name, test if the process is running and if yes, continue testing.

Comment: thanks  @Stephan . I have modified your code a little bit and it worked perfectly.